# Corner case of BVHTree's ray_cast(): ray hitting thru a vertex (not face) of the geometry?

Tags: geometry

I'm playing around [`BVHTree`'s `ray_cast()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.bvhtree.html#mathutils.bvhtree.BVHTree.ray_cast) method.

I pick a starting point, `s`, and compute the ray direction as `e - s`, where `e` is a vertex of the object. Then, I construct a BVH tree from this object and cast the ray.

```
obj_tree.ray_cast(s, e - s)
```

There's no other obstruction from `s` to `e`, except `e` itself.

According to my experiments, strangely, there are two outcomes for different vertices being `e`.

1. `ray_cast()` reports an intersection, and the intersection is just `e` (numerically; difference within, say, 1e-7);
2. `ray_cast()` reports no intersection.

Both make sense to me, but I'd expect only one of them happens.

Is this a bug from this corner case, or does `ray_cast()` have its reasons to report different results?

---

Relevant snippet of the code:

```
world2obj = obj.matrix_world.inverted()
start = world2obj * v1 # in world coordinates
end = world2obj * v2
direction = end - start
_, _, face_idx, dist = obj_tree.ray_cast(start, direction)
```

Comment: Please post more code than  `obj_tree.ray_cast(s, e - s)`  Have you, for instance, put the arguments to [BVHTree.ray_cast](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.bvhtree.html#mathutils.bvhtree.BVHTree.ray_cast) in object space?

Comment: Never used obj_tree.ray_cast but it can make sense if you take the computation errors into accout.(vector operations precision)

Comment: @batFINGER Thanks! I've supplemented the relevant part of my code. Yes, I did transform coordinates into the object space.